# Creating Hyperlink between sheets where they all are in same workbook

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, hyperlink

The code below creates a hyperlink but whenever I click on that hyperlink it says that it "Cannot Open specified file".

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
s1 = "C:/santosh_chikne/python/Excel/test1.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(s1)

ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Index")

a="A"

b="B"

rownums=4

col=2

sheetname=wb.get_sheet_names()

for i in sheetname:

    link = str(s1)+"#"+str(i)+"A1"

    url2 = str(i)

    ws.cell(row=rownums, column=col).hyperlink=link

    rownums=rownums+1

wb.save(s1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't test this because I don't have Python installed on my office machine, but I think something like this should do the job for you.

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a new workbook and add a worksheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hyperlink.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Hyperlinks')

# Format the first column
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)

# Add the standard url link format.
url_format = workbook.add_format({
    'font_color': 'blue',
    'underline':  1
})

# Add a sample alternative link format.
red_format = workbook.add_format({
    'font_color': 'red',
    'bold':       1,
    'underline':  1,
    'font_size':  12,
})

# Add an alternate description string to the URL.
string = 'Python home'

# Add a "tool tip" to the URL.
tip = 'Get the latest Python news here.'

# Write some hyperlinks
worksheet.write_url('A1', 'http://www.python.org/')  # Implicit format.
worksheet.write_url('A3', 'http://www.python.org/', url_format, string)
worksheet.write_url('A5', 'http://www.python.org/', url_format, string, tip)
worksheet.write_url('A7', 'http://www.python.org/', red_format)
worksheet.write_url('A9', 'mailto:jmcnamara@cpan.org', url_format, 'Mail me')

# Write a URL that isn't a hyperlink
worksheet.write_string('A11', 'http://www.python.org/')

workbook.close()
```

Or, this.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(workbookEx.xlsx) 
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("sheet1")

link = "workbookEx.xlsx#sheet2!E5"

ws.cell(row=1, column=1).hyperlink = (link)
```